# Found Well in Backyard -- How to install pump?

Tags: water, well, well-pump, irrigation

In my backyard there is this well, I think, that has water in it.

As you can see, there is a well casing and then a pipe in between. I have no idea how to install a pump and such, and am not sure where to start. I would love the idea of watering the large front yard lawn, or my garden with water.

I tried to measure the depth with a stick (*I thought the water was really high up*) but it fell and I did hear a splash as it hit the bottom. As you can see, there is an electrical port above, there likely was a pump here before. My neighbor also has a well and has a pump system setup for some sprinklers (*I think*), but I'm not sure how it works.

How would I connect a pump to the black pipe, which ends right with the well casing? *The well is set in an old concrete slab.*

[image]

Comment: How will you remove the stick so it does not get sucked into the pump?

Comment: A stick can't get sucked into a well pump. They're surrounded by a screen. However, it could obstruct insertion. Don't drop any more crap in there.

Comment: Voting to close as overly broad. Please ask something more specific. FYI, cost question are off topic here.

Comment: I imagined that I could try to fish it out, or, if I find out how deep it is, pour water into it to make the stick float to the top. It fell inside the casing, not the pipe, so I thought it would be okay. Sorry, I will try to make it more specific.

Comment: You'd have to fill the entire earth to float the stick to the top. :)

Comment: That pipe probably has a pump attached to it, FYI. Normally there's no pipe unless there's a pump.

Comment: Hmm. I think that could be the case. But my neighbor's pump is above ground (I think, there is something that looks like a pump above ground, and it's very rusty.) There is an electrical outlet that connects to the house above ground. As far as I know, there are no wires going down there.

Comment: If that is rigid pvc not poly it was probably a suction pump and it should not be hard to pull the pipe up , and don’t drop anything else in there.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you call a local "well guy" and ask him the same questions. They have the expertise to do everything "well" related including determining if that pipe or casing is really for an old well. If it is a well, he may have even been the guy that drilled the original well or knows who drilled it to get the specs of that hole in the ground.

Comment: Yes D.george. There are many types of pumps and control systems. There may even be a submersible pump at the end of that black pipe...but I don't see any wires so who knows?  Maybe just a footvalve.  You also need to know how much that well produces so you can properly match the pump size and not "pump it dry".   You need a pump/well guy!

Comment: Also worth checking if the LAHJ has records of the well. My state keeps a database, though it appears to be lacking on older wells, presumably due to when they started keeping records.

Comment: I see. This isn't some DIY job I can just do then, as in I can't just purchase a pump and attach to the well. I did a quick google search for "LAHJ records" and I wasn't able to find anything. What does "LAHJ" stand for? I'm not sure if the labor + pump cost of having this well work will be more than the cost to water the property itself!

Comment: LAHJ == Local Authority Having Jurisdiction - village/town/city/county/state depending on where you are and who has the responsibility, if any. In my area it's the State department of environmental protection that has authority over wells. Your area may differ, which is why LAHJ is more accurate than the one that applies to my area. You could certainly try pulling up on the inner pipe to see if it comes up with a pump attached. Without a cap there's probably a lot of trash other than your stick in there.

Comment: I see. There is a cap on it! I just took it off to show the inside. Thanks, I will take a look and see if I can find data about this.

Comment: Now I'm starting to wonder -- Could I attach a hand-pump to it without having to worry about draining too much / calling someone to check the well out? All the videos online seem to point on how to install a backup hand pump to an electric well, or how to dig out a new well for the hand pump. I'm not sure how I would attach one to the black pipe. The well probably has water at 25 feet.

Comment: And a well guy would do the job really well. (couldn't resist)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do anything with this well pull the pipe up.

If the water level is shallow it may come up easily as a single line with a foot valve.

If it’s a submersible it may not come up easy as the wires can be hanging it up, but in both cases pull that pipe up. If you can’t remove it you can’t really expect to use the well.

Once you pull the pipe the poly will probably have rust stains at the static water level. Once you know this level you can decide on the type of pump and size of pressure tank.

Comment: I see. It might be a submersible pump because I just noticed that there are actually some stray wires running out of the electrical port along with the panel for something to be plugged in. I believe the pipe is not PVC but rather poly because of its color (PVC pipe is usually white.) I wanted to first try and use a string to measure how deep it is, then maybe I can try to pull it out.